# Multiple SSH connections to the same system - is it possible?

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have a linux computer acting as a server which can accept incoming SSH connections.

Is it possible to reliably connect multiple devices at the same time, such as my phone and laptop, as well as other desktops, to the same server using SSH?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why didn't you just try before asking?

Comment: Not only this, but you can have multiple links between the same pair of systems. You may also find `screen` or `mosh` useful if you want the "Windows remote desktop" behaviour for the command line: a single interface which is passed around multiple links.

Comment: There are 2 reasons why I didn't simply try before asking; the first is the lack of faith I have in my own understanding of linux - if it had worked I would have still not trusted its reliability if I come to rely on it. The second is the the Superuser community is, generally speaking, awesome and quick to help those who ask - thanks community.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The short answer - Yes. It usually works by default.

The long answer - Depending on what you are using it for, it may slow down with multiple connections, but that is a bandwidth issue, not an ssh issue.

Answer (score 31):

Yes it is possible, it is the default behaviour.

### Trust

You **can rely if you are using an updated version** of `ssh` and the protocol is not any more 1.

```
grep "Protocol"  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The command above should give you `Protocol 2`.

### Limits for the connections

You can see `ssh` as the encrypted evolution of `telnet`, born in the far '69 to allow remote access to a server. Note that `ssh` connects over TCP and it is able to forward X-sessions (graphical session) too.
 Multitasking and multi-user are in the inner nature of Unix... even if it is not without limits !!!

You can see some of those **limits** in the TCP and SSH limits:

- `cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`, usually 128, to see the maximum TCP *outstanding* connection you can have;

  > The kern.ipc.somaxconn sysctl(8) variable limits the size of the listen queue for accepting new TCP connections. The default value of 128 is typically too low for robust handling of new connections on a heavily loaded web server.
- `cat /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog`, usually 1000, the maximum  length of the TCP packet queue
- `less /etc/security/limits.conf` you can find the limits for user.
- **MaxSessions** in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  > MaxSessions
  >   Specifies the maximum number of open sessions permitted per network connection. **The default is 10**.
- `#MaxStartups 10:30:60` usually commented in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and by default set to 10

  > Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections to the SSH daemon... The default is 10.

---

References

- `man ssh`, `man sshd` on your machine.
- The man page of [sshd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) or of [sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

Comment: `somaxconn` is the maximum number of *outstanding* connections, i.e. the maximum listen backlog, *not* the 'maximum number of TCP connection[s] you can have'. The maximum number of TCP connections you can have is orders of magnitude larger than 128. Otherwise practical servers would not be possible.

Comment: @ejp thanks for the spot, I was on hurry and I misses "new" before connection. BTW _"outstanding"_ is more precise. I added some words more in the hope it is more clear.

Comment: `MaxSessions` only limits the number of multiplexed sessions over a single TCP connection ([more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28085)) so it doesn't limit you to connect to the same host again. (A default limit of 10 for total ssh sessions would be absurd. imagine a shared webhost with hundreds or thousands of user accounts and only 10 ssh sessions allowed.)

Comment: @Josef It is written _MaxSessions Specifies the maximum number of open sessions permitted __per network connection__,_ nothing different (as reported in the man page): maybe not clear enough. Thanks for the additional reference and to underline this point. (Note: BTW the common use of a Linux computer with ssh is not a shared web host with 10^5+ users account, and in that case  the __default__ setting cannot  be appropriate by definition :-) )

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it totally is.
But this should be implementation-defined. You could as well program your own (probably not so secure, and worse) ssh server that cannot handle multiple connections. But just like common HTTP-Servers of course support this, openssh does so too.

Actually this is the very concept of Unix:
A multiuser system where a server does all the work and only small clients connect (terminals).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is very common. Indeed if used as a fileserver and by many users it is absolutely essential. SFTP uses SSH, and there is a lot of EDI activity that depends on it too.

From devices it is possible to trigger events with custom user logons (such as poweroff or reboot).

Consider also SCP (WinSCP is commonly used to access source code), and KDE users still able to use fish: in Konqueror.

Notable too is the use of additional ports in case of loss during maintenance (Ubuntu do-release-upgrade, say).

So yes,  I gather you have never had multiple PuTTY terminals open ?

Comment: No strangely enough I hadn't! But thank you for the extra information, what did you mean about additional ports for maintenance?

Comment: During do-relesase-upgrade from a remote terminal, there is a risk that comms will be lost (restart of SSH or network, say).  If these cannot be re-established on port 22 Ubuntu provides an alternative port 1022 using a second SSH instance. The update occurs inside "screen" which can be accessed with screen -x / screen -r after reconnecting and a sudo su. (look into "screen" and "tmux"). Plenty of information around on this.